# Printing a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to make a vector of vectors of type int and then print it out. I have this code in main.cpp.

```
Grid myGrid;
for (int i  = 0; i < myGrid.getdivas(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myGrid.getdivas(); j++)
    {
        cout << myGrid[i][j];
    }
}
```

My constructor for a grid is

```
Grid::Grid()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        vector<int> row; 
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
        {
            row.push_back(0); 
        }
        grid_.push_back(row);
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error in the cout statement:

> 'Grid' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/); the only thing which catched my eye is that in your constructor you initialize a `grid_` vector, but in your loop which prints the grid you attempt to access some `operator[]` on the `Grid` type. What does that return?

Comment: `.getdivas()`? I hope that will return Jennifer Lopez and Morrissey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be:

```
cout << myGrid.grid_[i][j]; // if grid_ is public
```

But you'll probably want to overload `operator[]` for you class. Better yet, have a member function that does the printing or overload `operator<<`.

Comment: It says gird_ is inaccessible if I do `cout << myGrid.grid_[i][j];`

Comment: That's because it's either `private` or `protected`.